# Where does a rotation go when I Apply it to a mesh?

Tags: python, objects

When you Apply a rotation to a mesh, where does it go, and where can you find it in bpy?

I.e. bpy.data.objects['mesh']. ...?

Comment: The vertices are rotated and the objects rotation is removed. But your question isnt clear.

Comment: It is quite possible that this is a question of not knowing what **apply** actually means in Blender. So just to make sure, do you mean that you actually applied the rotation, i.e. hit `Ctrl` `A` followed by `R` or clicked _Object_ -> _Apply_ -> _Rotation_, or do you mean that you just rotated the object?

Answer (score 3):

The transformation is applied directly to the world space locations of the vertices/edges/faces, then removed from the object transform. As a result, it is lost, as it is no longer distinguishable from any other change to the base mesh data. Such as edit mode changes, other applied transforms, applied modifiers, or the original script/primitive/tool that spawned geo there in the first place.